# Position a dynamically sized div at certain percentage from top or bottom

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a div that contains an image with the idea of making sure the image is scaled to fit the width of the window. 
That works fine, but I fail to position the image correctly horizontally; I would like to have it at somewhere at the bottom of the window, but it sticks to the top.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="page" id=""><div id="imagewrap"><img id="test" src="myimage.png" width="100%"></div></div>
```

The CSS is like this:

```
#imagewrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border:2px solid;
}
```

This is meant to work on Android phones (cordova) so any advice can be specific for that rendering engine (webkit)

Current version after using some of the comments below which is at the bottom but doesn't center:

```
#centerdiv {
height: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border:2px solid;
width: 70%;

}
#imagewrap {
border:2px solid;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0; /** percentage FROM bottom here **/
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Toying with inline-blocks inside fixed-size blocks with text-align?

Comment: absolute position with given bottom is likely the best solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this css:

```
#page {
  position: relative;
}

#imagewrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; /** percentage FROM bottom here, currently this is at the bottom **/
}
```

Keep in mind that this will be relevant to the bottom of the `#page` div.

Comment: Ok, that worked. I have now added position: absolute; and bottom: 0 to the #imagewrap img selector too so that the image is at the bottom of the imagewrap div. Only problem I have now is that the centering vertically which I did with the margin left and right on auto doesn't work anymore

Comment: Absolute positioning does that.  It is meant to be a blunt "you stay put Mr. and don't go ANYWHERE!" kind of tool.  If you want to get your margins back, try changing your original `#imagewrap` rules to `#imagewrap > img`.  If that doesn't work, wrap the img in yet another div, and put your centering/margin css rules on that.

Comment: tried that but somehow can't get it to center normally; the div centers but the image is not full width of the div so it appears not centered..I added the current CSS